# DOM versus Castor

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, castor

Can anyone tell me which one better to use for xml parsing - DOM or Castor (with criterion being lesser memory usage)?

Comment: You could benchmark it and find out for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will create an object graph in memory containing all the unmarshalled objects. I wouldn't expect a big advantage from one over the other in terms of memory use.